How to control servo with Raspberry Pi by internet connection?
I want to send a command from my smart phone to move a servo at my house when I am at the work. Is it possible to do that with the Raspberry Pi and a wifi module? I am not an expert in this field, so I would be grateful if you explain how to do it. Thanks. (Raspberry Pi won't connected to a PC via USB, it will be connected just a battery, servo, and wifi module.)

I use a Pi to control Solar Inverter in my Attic. The Pi is hard wired to inverter and on the WiFi. I use RealVNC for which I have a free account. I run the RealVNC Viewer on my Android phone. I can create a VNC connection to the Pi which lets me look at the Pi screen and toggle buttons etc. You could use the same technique. This link may be helpful https://www.realvnc.com/en/blog/raspberry-pi-vnc/?__lai_s=0.43348372435369553&__lai_sr=40-44&__lai_sl=m
